# The libc function "system" does not get linked in the executable produced by GCC even after using the static flag

Tags: c, gdb, static-linking, libc

I am new to systems programming. I was just trying to implement the [ret2libc attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-to-libc_attack) on my own. To implement that, I need the address of the start of the libc function "system" in the executable.

I tried to do static linking, but to my surprise, the "system" function is not getting linked in my executable.

Below is a simple program saved as `t.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int fun()
{
    int x;
}int main()
{
    fun();
    int x;
    x=10;
    printf("%d\n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the output which I get when using GDB:

```
abhishek@abhishek:~$ gcc -g -static t.c -o t
abhishek@abhishek:~$ gdb -q t
Reading symbols from t...
(gdb) print system
No symbol "system" in current context.
(gdb) print memcpy
$1 = {<text gnu-indirect-function variable, no debug info>} 0x422b40 <memcpy>
(gdb) print strcmp
$2 = {<text gnu-indirect-function variable, no debug info>} 0x421b50 <strcmp_ifunc>
(gdb) print printf
$3 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x40b5b0 <printf>
(gdb) quit
abhishek@abhishek:~$
```

libc functions like `memcpy`, `strcmp` and even `printf` is getting linked. But not the function `system`. The tutorials out on the internet just asks to get the address of `system` and then proceed accordingly. But I am unable to get the address of `system` in the first place.

Could anyone help me why the function `system` is not linked even when I am using the `-static` flag in GCC?

Comment: You're not using the `system()` function. Only functions (or actually the compliation unit the function is part of) gets linked in. printf and the libc runtime itself may call other functions such as memcpy/strcmp  so those get linked in.

Comment: ... add some function that calls `system` to your code, so it gets linked into your executable, like `void foo(void) {system("bar");}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an executable is linked against a library, *and* the library is built correctly<sup>*</sup>, only called functions of the library are included in the final executable.

Since your program does not call `system()`, and no other function calls it, it is apparently not included.

The solution is to call `system()`, for example in an unused control branch.

---

*) A library commonly contains modules, which are compiled from translation units. Such a translation unit is commonly a source file. For example, if your libc were built with a module that includes both `printf()` *and* `system()`, the latter function would be in the executable, even if it only calls `printf()`.

Common linkers only include modules that resolve references that are unresolved at that step.

Comment: I was going through the tutorial here: https://youtu.be/Gu_JGaWpcn4?t=438 from IIT Madras and also the tutorial here: https://www.ired.team/offensive-security/code-injection-process-injection/binary-exploitation/return-to-libc-ret2libc Each of them uses simple programs which does not call `system` on its own. But still when they open GDB and give the command `print system` the address of print shows the address of `system`. The same program on a similar system (Lubuntu 22.04 and GCC 11.2.0) I am unable to locate `system`.

Comment: Intuitively I too had the idea that unless a function gets used it is not linked. (I guess I read in the book : C- Complete Reference by Herbert Schildt). But the way they were doing it in the above two tutorials I thought that I might have been wrong... (especially since the book has negative reviews...)

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh that may be the case on that particular environnment where `system` gets linked into your final executable for some reason. You might ask the people that made the tutorial for more details. In the meantime try what has been suggested here.

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh BTW, all those tutorials that show how to exploit security breaches often don't not work anymore, because your environnement is different from that the authors had when they write the article/tutorial. DIfferent OS, deifferent version of the compiler, different compiler alltogether etc., etc.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I have already tried it. I mean to check that, I had removed the `printf` statement and GDB could no longer find the address of `printf`. Similarly, when I used a dummy `system` function in my program, `system` was present in the executable... But I was not sure why it was not working... I was thinking probably, `system` was in a seperate library which was not getting linked automatically.. But when I saw the same with `printf`, I felt like asking it here, for more clarification...

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh so is everything clear now?

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes... To a great extent.. but I would like to contact the author of the first video tutorial for the details regarding the setup (as you said).

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh Looking at the video at 09:20, when the instructor runs `info proc map`, it turns out that the executable has linked libc dynamically.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick yes I also sort of figured out the same in the morning today. But in my system when I perform `print system` (when the system is dynamically linked) I get the function name written as : `0xb7e56310 <__libc_system>` . But in his setup, when he does `print system` he gets the output as `0xf7e42940 <system>`, similar to the output when something is statically linked (in static linking we do not get the `__libc_` prefix, I think, we get just the function name, not sure though, said it based on my observations), that is why I was wondering. But anyways, thanks for clarifying...